How to make this python code not run into a grammar error each time using NTLK
I am writing some code for a final project in a writing-coding class. I am a beginner aswell. I wrote some code below to create a randomized poem, but every time I run it, I always get an error that some word doesnt follow the grammar rules
import nltk
nltk.download('words')
nltk.download('punkt')
from nltk.corpus import words
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
from nltk.grammar import CFG
from random import choice

# Choose a random word from the English dictionary
chosen_word = choice(words.words())

# Define the context free grammar
grammar = CFG.fromstring("""
S -> NP VP
NP -> Det N
VP -> V NP
Det -> 'the' | 'a'
N -> 'cat' | 'dog' | 'bird' | 'tree' | 'flower' | 'chosen_word' | 'Fabrikoid'
V -> 'sings' | 'walks' | 'flies' | 'grows' | 'blooms'
""")

# Create a parser object
parser = nltk.ChartParser(grammar)

# Generate a random sentence using the chosen word
sentence = ""
while not sentence:
    # Generate a parse tree for the chosen word
    trees = list(parser.parse(word_tokenize(chosen_word)))

    # Choose a random parse tree
    tree = choice(trees)

    # Generate a sentence from the parse tree
    sentence = tree.label()
    for subtree in tree.subtrees():
        if subtree.label() in ["NP", "VP"]:
            sentence += " " + " ".join(subtree.leaves())

# Print the generated poem
print("Here is your poem:")
print(sentence)

I ran the program, expecting a sort of randomized poem to form. Instead, I get this:
ValueError                                
Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-57-d6c4184eb90e> in <cell line: 27>()
     27 while not sentence:
     28     # Generate a parse tree for the chosen word
---> 29     trees = list(parser.parse(word_tokenize(chosen_word)))
     30 
     31     # Choose a random parse tree

2 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/nltk/grammar.py in check_coverage(self, tokens)
    663         if missing:
    664             missing = ", ".join(f"{w!r}" for w in missing)
--> 665             raise ValueError(
    666                 "Grammar does not cover some of the " "input words: %r." % missing
    667             )

ValueError: Grammar does not cover some of the input words: "'unimprovedness'".


It looks like you want to insert your chosen word into your grammar here: ... 'flower' | 'chosen_word' | 'Fabrikoid' .... You are adding the literal string 'chosen_word' though.
I would recommend using an f-string. Put an f before your opening string block here: CFG.fromstring(f""" and then use ... | '{chosen_word}' | ...
